# Lightswitch: Stop Windows Service

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I have a small desktop application built in LightSwitch that allows remote Sales Staff to log and work with customer data locally on their laptops as the customer sites don't always have internet/VPN access. As such, each client application has a local install of SQL 2012 Express.

In the command bar, I have a button labeled, "Database Backup" that is meant to copy their .mdf file from their machine to a mapped network drive when they get back into the office. Works fine on a test .mdf file that currently isn't attached to a SQL instance. The problem now is when trying to copy that .mdf file in production (with SQL running), it can't copy since it's open in SQL Express.

My question is this: Is there a reference I can add to the client that will allow me to use the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController class? Or what would be the best assembly to use so that I could stop then restart a Windows service? (Stop the service => copy mdf file => restart service)

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to ensure that I understand your topology.  I'm assuming your app is configured as a Silverlight Desktop app that is deployed as a 2-tier environment where the app and database are hosted on the same machine.

With that being the case, you should be able to write code for your app so that it can call into the ServiceController class.  You just can't do it from the "client" code since that is Silverlight and doesn't have access to ServiceController.  Instead, you'll need to write it in the "server" code which runs as a host process on the same machine and has access to the full .NET Framework.  You can expose your custom server code through a Web API that your client code can invoke when the user clicks the button.  Here's a good article explaining this pattern: http://blog.pragmaswitch.com/?p=765.